# Tag Nuke Requests [comcast] and [verizon-wireless]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, retag-request

The [comcast](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/comcast) and [verizon-wireless](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/verizon-wireless) tags are on 16 and 24 questions respectively. As they are typical US-only ISP's could the tags be removed?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've nuked questions with [att](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/att),[sprint](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/sprint),[comcast](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/comcast) and [4g](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/4g) since they were all low quality.

Verizon remains, there are some good questions which do benefit from the tag.

Comment: Aren't they too localized for a world-wide audience?

Comment: @Daniel What % of SU users does a tag need to be relevant to in order to not be too 'localized'?

Comment: @DarthAndroid Then petition to change the description to not refer to geography (population is implied), but relevant user count on this site. But keeping US-specific stuff, and closing [this](http://superuser.com/questions/335575/free-ftp-hosting) is ridiculous -- the other four users voted to close as *too localized*, as it only affects 1.3 billion people.